# Magento getUrlPath() won't work

Tags: php, magento

I've this multi site/store setup with magento and I'm having a problem with  `$_product->getUrlPath()` . I've these 2 shops and when I display the products of both on homepage it shows me always the same links

when I'm in shop 1 (for all the products even if they are not from shop 1): shop1.com/product-name.html

when I'm in shop 2 (same here): shop1.com/product-name.html instead of shop2.com/product-name.html

I've tried also with `$_product->getProductUrlRewrite()` and `$_product->getProductUrl()`
and also with `$_product->getUrlKey()` but nothing, it's always the same thing.

Comment: I know you've probably already done this - but have you tried clearing the cache then re-indexing everything?

Comment: yes, both magento and browsers cache even if magento's one is disabled. + reindexed it but still have that problem
why they do not have a good wiki like wordpress, whyyY?! :/

Comment: Tell me about it :( I've spent the last month struggling with Magento!

Comment: Unfortunately though, I'm no guru - I'm guessing you're not getting any errors thrown in you php log file, or your magento system.log / exception.log files?

Comment: one thing I've noticed is that when $_product->getUrlPath() is outside an <a> it only shows product-name.html but when it's inside <a> it adds the url of the main shop. O.o

Comment: That will either be the browser formatting the `<a>` tag, or Magento doing it, I wouldn't worry too much about that

Comment: hhmmm, if you don't have any errors / exceptions to go off of I wouldn't really know where to start :/ it sounds like you've got the stores correctly linked and setup in the backend. When did this stop working? Just recently? Or has it never worked?

Comment: without errors it's a nightmare! I've tried everything but still nothing. If I can't find a way to make it work, I've to create plain php script to take all the info from the  database, and that's not good at all. No, it never worked.

Comment: If I were you I'd try backing up the database and downloading a fresh version of Magento, see if you can get it working properly on there with all the default settings / themes

Comment: Obviously that could take a while, if you want a faster solutions I'd recommend trying the Magento forums, sorry I can't really help you :/

Comment: yeah at this point I'll try that too, wish me luck! Thank you Sean!! :)

Comment: No problem :) hope you manage to get it sorted!

Comment: have you tried changing the shop you are in? ie `Mage::app('shop2_english');` vs. `Mage::app('shop1_english');`?

Answer (score 2):

Your product will return its URL with the loaded store in mind, unless you've changed it somewhere in the middle or specifically set which store you want to get product attributes from.

So, first thing you need to do, is to make sure that you've got the right store loaded by checking

```
Mage::app()->getStore();
```

If returned store is not the one that you've expected, then check what store is set when calling the initial

```
Mage::run();
```

in index.php.

If the store IS the one you want and/or you just want to show product url for a different store, then you can set, on your product model, which store you want to use by calling

```
$_product->setStoreId(YOUR_STORE_ID)
```

This will set the product store and you can get it's URL from that store. So, calling

```
$_product->setStoreId(YOUR_STORE_ID)->getProductUrl();
```

will return product URL for the desired store.